# IsNumeric() allowing minus at last of the values

Tags: vb.net

I am using `IsNumeric()` function in my code to validate numbers.

`IsNumeric(100)`  - true,
`IsNumeric(-100)` - true,
`IsNumeric(+100)` - true,

`IsNumeric(100-)` - **true** - I have doubt in this. (100-) Is this a valid number? IsNumeric () returns true to this value.

```
    Dim latitude As String = "12.56346-"
    If IsNumeric(latitude) Then
        If (Convert.ToDouble(latitude) >= -90 And Convert.ToDouble(latitude) <= 90) Then
            isValidLatitude.Text = "true"
        Else
            isValidLatitude.Text = "false"
        End If
     Else
        isValidLatitude.Text = "false"
     End If
```

Error while converting `latitude` to double

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Comment: what is problem?

Comment: you will get exception in convert.todouble line..string format isse

Comment: Yes, I am getting a conversion problem. "Input string was not in a correct format. "

Comment: @so , what do you want do?

Comment: I need to know, how IsNumeric() is working? Because I expect "false" to the value "12.56346-"

Comment: And then I think "12.56346-" is not a valid number

Comment: @Vijay as you asked to understand why IsNumeric is returning `true` for a invalid number, I described a possible explanation. I also give you a solution for your exact situation using a standard method from .net code, which would work as expected, and also is the recommended way to solve this problem by the Microsoft itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: my previous answers were wrong about assuming it was a bug. As the answer of @Damien_The_Unbeliever states, this function tries to validate the string as a lot of data types. And actually, the value `"100-"` is a valid `Decimal` number. That's why it returns true (as it's a "valid" Decimal) but gives a exception when converting to Double (as it's not a valid Double). @Damien_The_Unbeliever really deserves your +1 for pointing that.

From the documentation (showing all the data types that IsNumeric tries to validate):

> IsNumeric returns True if the data type of Expression is Boolean, Byte, Decimal, Double, Integer, Long, SByte, Short, Single, UInteger, ULong, or UShort. It also returns True if Expression is a Char, String, or Object that can be successfully converted to a number. Expression can contain non-numeric characters. IsNumeric returns True if Expression is a string that contains a valid hexadecimal or octal number. IsNumeric also returns True if Expression contains a valid numeric expression that begins with a + or - character or contains commas.

Also, @CaiusJard did a nice search and pointed out that inner methods use a `NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign` option, which allows this behavior.

**Ok, now to the solution:**

Just use a `TryParse` method, from your desired data type (`int`, `long`, etc...). The cool thing is that it'll behaves exactly as you expect, and if the parsing is successful, we have the parsed value already available to use!

```
if (Int32.TryParse(value, out int number))
{
    // String is a valid number, and is already parsed in the 'number' variable!
}

else
{
    // String is not a valid number!
}
```

**Solution's VB.Net version:**

```
Dim value As String = "12.56346-"
Dim number As Double = 0
If Double.TryParse(value, number) Then
    ' String is a valid number, and is already parsed in the "number" variable!
    isValidLatitude.Text = "true"
Else
    ' String is not a valid number!
    isValidLatitude.Text = "false"
End If
```

Comment: Or even `isValidLatitude.Text = Double.TryParse(value, number).ToString()`

Comment: First of all, 'isNumeric(100-') typed in the edit windows results in a "Expected expression" error. but '        Dim str As String = "100-"        Dim sint As Integer = CInt(str)' does not fail and infact sint is -100 . You should parse the input string and make sure does not end with non-number

Comment: @CaiusJard nice short version!

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli exactly. That's why my proposed solution uses the TryParse method, since it really parses the number, and even is the recommended solution on documentation

Comment: Please read this: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExploringIsNumericForC.aspx I didn't downvote! Someone else must have, it wasn't me.

Comment: I downvoted because if string is "100-" Double.Tryparse returns 0, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli That's why I surrounded its use with a `if` condition, and also inserted a comment saying `String is not a valid number!`. Also, looking in OP's question, he/she only states that need to know if it's valid or not. OP didn't specified the further use of the variable.

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli Double.TryParse returns a Boolean, not a number

Comment: (If the conversion fails, the number you passed as the output parameter is set to 0, but that doesn't mean the string value you passed in was converted to 0; you're supposed to inspect the returned Boolean and only use the out value if the result is true. If conversion fails the passed in value is set to the default for the type, typically 0. Vitox's answer is factually correct with regards to the TryParse advice, and it is helpful. a downvote based on misunderstanding of TryParse would be unwarranted

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you, I could not said that better.

Comment: @JeremyThompson thanks for the link. I included it in my answer. It looks like a strange implementation. Unfortunately i can't spend more time to inspect it, but I suspect it is a implementation error, since it's not in accordance to the documentation.

Comment: Not worth a down vote but `Dim number As Double = Nothing` doesn't seem quite right. I don't think a value type can be `Nothing` (null) without the `?`. If you examine `number`, I think you will find it is 0.

Comment: @Mary - The compiler doesn't allow you to declare a nullable double variable and use it on the `TryParse` method. It gives you a `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Nullable object must have a value.'` exception. But I see your point about declaring it to null, and you are right. I'll change it to make it more clear.

Comment: @Mary you're right, it can't be nothing, but it can be set to Nothing (in which case it just acquires its default value. From the Lang reference: Assigning Nothing to a variable sets it to the default value for its declared type. If that type contains variable members, they are all set to their default values" and also "If the variable is of a reference type — that is, an object variable — Nothing means the variable is not associated with any object."). It's like c#'s `int x = default(int);`

Answer (score 7):

`IsNumeric` is from the [Microsoft.VisualBasic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.information.isnumeric?view=netframework-4.8) namespace/dll, a bunch of helper stuff intended to help VB6 programmers get their arcane VB6 code /knowledge working on VB.NET

You'll note if you use other functions from the same dll such as `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion.Int()`, or you use dedicated VB.NET converters such as `CInt` or `CDbl` these will also cope with a trailing minus sign and return a negative value

If you want to dispense with the old ways of VB6, use a numeric type's TryParse.. but all in, be consistent / if you use a function from Microsoft.VisualBasic to determine if a conversion can be made, use the vb conversion because within itself the package will be consistent but between Microsoft.VB and normal .net System there are some differences in behavior

---

Edit:

A couple of people have been wondering about the source code and how it uses TryParse, so why doesn't it work like using TryParse directly?

`Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric()` uses `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DoubleType.TryParse()` to determine whether an expression is numeric. This `DoubleType.TryParse` is not the same as `Double.TryParse` - it is a helper method again in the VB namespace that specifically sets the `NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign` flag among many other flags. When parsing the number (first as non currency related, using Double.Parse, then if it fails a second attempt is made using adjusted values for currency related tests) this AllowTrailingSign flag will be considered in conjunction with other regional number formatting rules in determining if the passed in value is numeric

You'll note that on a machine obeying a USA number formatting culture, a string of "(100$)" is also declared to be numeric but calling `Double.TryParse("(100$)", x)` will also return false. The VB helper methods here are being a lot more liberal in what they accept than the System methods, because they're telling the System methods to be more liberal than they are by default

As noted, I've always regarded the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace as a bunch of helper methods intended to allow terrible old VB6 code to be pasted into VB.NET and work with minimal fiddling. I wouldn't advocate using it for new projects and I remove the reference when I work on VB.NET - using it to support the VB6 notions of "just sling anything in, of any type, and it'll probably figure it out and work.. and if it doesn't we can always on error resume next" should be discarded in favour of precise and accurate about the operations executed and their intent

Comment: Did you saw the documentation of this function, and the code provided by @JeremyThompson? The code seems to have the `TryParse` method, but does some weird comparisions before it, and since it's not in accordance to the documentation, it seems like a bug to me. I even added a comparision between methods on my previous answer.

Answer (score 3):

`IsNumeric` answers a question no sane person wants to ask. As quoted by [Vitox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62079575/15498):

> IsNumeric returns True if the data type of Expression is Boolean, Byte, Decimal, Double, Integer, Long, SByte, Short, Single, UInteger, ULong, or UShort. It also returns True if Expression is a Char, String, or Object that can be successfully converted to a number.

Note, it doesn't tell you that the given string can be converted to *all* numeric types. It tells you that the string can be converted to *at least one* numeric type. And for bonus bad style points, of course, it doesn't tell you *which* types the string can be converted to.

`Decimal.Parse("100-")` will execute perfectly well and give you a `Decimal` containing a value of -100.

So, it's **not a bug**, it's a bad function that has been retained for backwards compatibility reasons. Nowadays, we know better, and that we want to test whether a string can be converted to a *specific* data type, for which the `TryParse` family of functions have been designed.

Comment: `Decimal.Parse("100-")` there is the trick. You are right, it's a "valid" conversion. I'll edit my answer and also reference yours.